# datatable is empty vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, dataset

I'm not familiar with .net languages. but I tried to copy a datagridview rows to a datatable.when I use Watch on my datatable it has values but when i try to watch dataset,my datatable is empty. here is my code :

```
Dim dt As New DataTable("repTable")

    For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In dgrMatchesExacutives.Columns
        dt.Columns.Add(col.HeaderText)
    Next

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgrMatchesExacutives.Rows
        Dim dRow As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
            dRow(cell.ColumnIndex) = cell.Value
        Next
        dt.Rows.Add(dRow)
    Next

    If ds.Tables.Contains("repTable") Then
        ds.Tables.Remove("repTable")
    End If

    ds.Tables.Add("repTable")
```

Answer (score 0):

The Tables property of the DataSet is a DataTableCollection and you add items to this collection using the [provided overloads of the Add method.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.DataTableCollection_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) But if you call the overload that receives a string you CREATE a NEW datatable (empty of course). The fact that you call the created datatable with the same name of the existing one has no relevance for the dataset.

If you have manually created a datatable and prepared it yourself with a schema and records then you need to use the [overload that takes a DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/as4zy2kc(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
 ds.Tables.Add(dt)
```